# Rest API Status code

Tags: node.js, rest, http

I have an API to check if a user exists.

```
POST /apis/user
[username=user]
```

in case of user already existing, the API needs to return a meaningful status that says the user is already existing.

If the user exists, I am returning 200OK.

In case the user does not exist, what should be the return status
A> `404 Not Found`
OR
B> `200OK`(since the API is accessible anyway) with a message {user already exists}

Comment: Why not `GET/apis/user/ID` with a 404 whe the user doesn't exist?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather let the http request succeed and return data that indicates whether the user exists or not?  This separates transports issues from the response.  You use http errors for transport issues and you return an actual response that tells whether the user exists or not.  Imagine a slight misspelling in the request also generates a 404.  Do you really want those two examples to look alike?  I wouldn't.  I'd return a JSON result with the results of the query.

Comment: @jgillich: That is the simple option, but it has to be POST.

Comment: @Tirtha Why "it has to be POST" ? When you need a jar from a shelf, you "get" it, not "post" it. Your API architecture is wrong.

Comment: @AlexandruG.: Lets say, I'm delegating the action to another guy who will tell me if the jar exists on the shelf or not. If it exists, then I'll ask him to get it for me. ;-)

Comment: @Tirtha Even then you should use same "standard language" when you talk to the *other guy*, not invent a new one ( *i.e: GET method when you want to fetch some information, POST method when you want to add/full update, PATCH method when you want to partial update, etc* ). If you respected the standards from the beginning, you wouldn't have this question to ask on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a text document I keep handy when working with RESTful APIs. In some ways it's a guessing game, but mainly **keep your API consistent**. You'll find some debate on when to use 401 vs 403 (among others), or more than one type that *could* apply for a particular error. Just be consistent, and your API and error messages will make sense to those using it, and to you while you're debugging.

```
var STATUS_CODES = exports.STATUS_CODES = {
  100 : 'Continue',
  101 : 'Switching Protocols',
  102 : 'Processing',                 // RFC 2518, obsoleted by RFC 4918
  200 : 'OK',
  201 : 'Created',
  202 : 'Accepted',
  203 : 'Non-Authoritative Information',
  204 : 'No Content',
  205 : 'Reset Content',
  206 : 'Partial Content',
  207 : 'Multi-Status',               // RFC 4918
  300 : 'Multiple Choices',
  301 : 'Moved Permanently',
  302 : 'Moved Temporarily',
  303 : 'See Other',
  304 : 'Not Modified',
  305 : 'Use Proxy',
  307 : 'Temporary Redirect',
  400 : 'Bad Request',
  401 : 'Unauthorized',
  402 : 'Payment Required',
  403 : 'Forbidden',
  404 : 'Not Found',
  405 : 'Method Not Allowed',
  406 : 'Not Acceptable',
  407 : 'Proxy Authentication Required',
  408 : 'Request Time-out',
  409 : 'Conflict',
  410 : 'Gone',
  411 : 'Length Required',
  412 : 'Precondition Failed',
  413 : 'Request Entity Too Large',
  414 : 'Request-URI Too Large',
  415 : 'Unsupported Media Type',
  416 : 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
  417 : 'Expectation Failed',
  418 : 'I\'m a teapot',              // RFC 2324
  422 : 'Unprocessable Entity',       // RFC 4918
  423 : 'Locked',                     // RFC 4918
  424 : 'Failed Dependency',          // RFC 4918
  425 : 'Unordered Collection',       // RFC 4918
  426 : 'Upgrade Required',           // RFC 2817
  500 : 'Internal Server Error',
  501 : 'Not Implemented',
  502 : 'Bad Gateway',
  503 : 'Service Unavailable',
  504 : 'Gateway Time-out',
  505 : 'HTTP Version not supported',
  506 : 'Variant Also Negotiates',    // RFC 2295
  507 : 'Insufficient Storage',       // RFC 4918
  509 : 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded',
  510 : 'Not Extended'                // RFC 2774
};

Nodejs Restify

BadDigestError: 400,
BadMethodError: 405,
InternalError: 500, // Don't have InternalErrorError
InvalidArgumentError: 409,
InvalidContentError: 400,
InvalidCredentialsError: 401,
InvalidHeaderError: 400,
InvalidVersionError: 400,
MissingParameterError: 409,
NotAuthorizedError: 403,
PreconditionFailedError: 412,
RequestExpiredError: 400,
RequestThrottledError: 429,
ResourceNotFoundError: 404,
WrongAcceptError: 406
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the [normative definition of 4xx HTTP error status](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1) (errors caused by the client), you will see that the only suitable definition is:

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.

This definition corresponds to `403 Forbidden`.

Please note that:

> If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity.

So, the `403 Forbidden` response code is not enough. You should also emit "User already exists!" in the response payload.

Answer (score 0):

The operation should be `GET /api/users/username:user` or `GET /api/users?username="user"`. GET is a better method in this case than POST. You can use OPTIONS or HEAD too if you want to check for existence only, and you don't want a response body (but they are not widely used). By GET you can use prefer header for the same purposes.

You can return an empty collection or 404 if not found, your choice. I think 404 is better because you wait only a single result in this case, and the name is probably a unique identifier.